# Chess minimax algorithm always returns first move

Tags: javascript, chess, minimax

I have implemented all the rules of chess, and tested all the relevant functions such as move generation and terminal state detection ie: draws, and checkmates. However, after I wrote the minimax function, with basic move ordering and alpha-beta pruning it would always return the first move from the move generation. Also, when testing it with mate in 1 positions, with a small amount of pieces, to a large amount of pieces, it seems to take forever (may be a crash or infinite loop). This couldn't have happened because of speed issues since when I performance tested all the functions, I could call them between 60-200 thousand times per second). Here's the code:

```
let board = [
    ["C", "H", "B", "Q", "K", "B", "H", "C"], 
    ["P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P"], 
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    ["p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p"],
    ["c", "h", "b", "q", "k", "b", "h", "c"]
];

function updateMovedCastlesAndKings(movedCastlesAndKings, board) {
    return {
        hasWKMoved: board[7][4] == " " || movedCastlesAndKings.hasWKMoved,
        hasWKSCMoved: board[7][7] == " " || movedCastlesAndKings.hasWKSCMoved,
        hasWQSCMoved: board[7][0] == " " || movedCastlesAndKings.hasWQSCMoved,
        hasBKMoved:  board[0][4] == " " || movedCastlesAndKings.hasBKMoved,
        hasBKSCMoved: board[0][7] == " " || movedCastlesAndKings.hasBKSCMoved,
        hasBQSCMoved: board[0][0] == " " || movedCastlesAndKings.hasBQSCMoved
    };
}

function alphaBeta(board,
    depth,
    alpha,
    beta, 
    color, 
    movedCastlesAndKings, 
    castlingPerms, 
    enpassantSquare, 
    halfMoveClock, 
    boardHistory,
    isNullOK) {
    if (color == 1) {
        var type = "w";
        var oppositeType = "b";
        var indexInHistoryTable = 1;
    } else {
        var type = "b"; 
        var oppositeType = "w";
        var indexInHistoryTable = 0;
    }

    let kingPosition = findKing(board, type);
    let moves = generateLegalMoves(enpassantSquare, castlingPerms, kingPosition, board, type);
    let amountOfMoves = moves.length;
    let isSideInCheck = isSquareUnderAttack(kingPosition, board, type);
    let isTerminal = isTerminalNode(boardHistory, halfMoveClock, amountOfMoves, isSideInCheck, board);
    let isEndgameState = isEndgame(board);

    if (isTerminal || depth == 0) {
        if (isTerminal) {
            if (type == "w" && isCheckmate(amountOfMoves, isSideInCheck)) {
                return {
                    score: color * -2000
                };
            }
            if (type == "b" && isCheckmate(amountOfMoves, isSideInCheck)) {
                return {
                    score: color * 2000
                };
            }
            return {
                score: 0
            };
        } else {
            return {
                score: color * evaluate(isEndgameState, board)
            };
        }
    }

    if (isNullOK && depth >= 3 && !isEndgameState && !isSideInCheck) {
        color *= -1;

        let value = -alphaBeta(board,
            depth - 3,
            -beta,
            10 - beta,
            color,
            movedCastlesAndKings,
            castlingPerms,
            undefined,
            halfMoveClock,
            boardHistory,
            false).score;

        color *= -1;

        if (value >= beta) {
            return {
                score: value
            };
        }
    }

    let bestValue = -Infinity;
    let bestMove;

    for (moveIndex = 0; moveIndex < amountOfMoves; moveIndex++) {
        let moveItem = moves[moveIndex];
        let nextNode = moveItem.node;
        let isPawnMove = moveItem.isPawnMove;
        let isCapture = moveItem.targetSQ;
        let doublePawnMove = moveItem.doublePawnMove;
        let updatedMovedCastlesAndKings = updateMovedCastlesAndKings(movedCastlesAndKings, nextNode);
        let nextEnpassantSquare = getEnpassantSquare(doublePawnMove, nextNode, oppositeType);
        let nextCastlingPerms = castlingPermissions(updatedMovedCastlesAndKings, nextNode);
        let hashIndex = makeHashTableIndex(nextCastlingPerms, nextEnpassantSquare, nextNode, oppositeType);
        let boardHistoryCopy = clone1DArray(boardHistory);
        let nextHalfMoveClock = halfMoveClock;

        boardHistoryCopy.push(hashIndex);

        isPawnMove || isCapture ? nextHalfMoveClock = 0 : nextHalfMoveClock += 1;

        let value = -alphaBeta(nextNode,
            depth - 1,
            -beta,
            -alpha,
            -color,
            updatedMovedCastlesAndKings,
            nextCastlingPerms,
            nextEnpassantSquare,
            nextHalfMoveClock,
            boardHistoryCopy,
            true).score;

        if (value > bestValue) {
            bestValue = value;
            bestMove = moveItem;
        }

        alpha = Math.max(alpha, bestValue);

        if (alpha >= beta) break;
    }

    if (!bestMove.targetSQ) {
        let from = bestMove.from;
        let to = bestMove.to;

        historyTable[indexInHistoryTable][from.y][from.x][to.y][to.x] += depth ** 2;
    }

    return {
        score: bestValue,
        move: bestMove
    };
}
```

If you need any clarifications to improve the question, feel free to respond. (note: the search algorithm uses a variant of minimax, called negamax, with null move pruning)

Comment: Have you check with check-mate in 1 move but with minimal number of figures?

Comment: @Tajniak What do you mean by "minimal number of figures"?

Comment: @Tajniak If you mean mate in 1 with a little amount of pieces, the program suffers the same errors.

Comment: Yes, sorry for missunderstanding. Best solution would be to debug this code step by step with minimal number figures of board but still few moves to do, i.e. 2 moves to mate. Code is to complex for me to debug it by just look and there are some unknowns, like meaning of isNullOK parameter.